# Getting input file name and directory with wolframscript

Tags: files-and-directories, scripting

I have the following script:

```
$ cat mathtest.m
pardir=DirectoryName @ $InputFileName;
Print["test parent dir: ", pardir]
```

If I run it like this, I get:

```
$ wolfram -script mathtest.m
test parent dir: /home/me/
```

If I run it like this, I get:

```
$ wolframscript -file mathtest.m
test parent dir:
```

Could somebody explain me this weird behavior? Apart from this I haven't noted any differences between running scripts in both methods. However, I do need the second one to give me the correct path.

I am on Wolfram Language 11.1.1 Engine for Linux x86 (64-bit).

Comment: What does it return for: `Print["test parent dir: ", {$InputFileName, NotebookFileName[]}]`?

Comment: @Kuba `NotebookFileName[]` should only work with a front end, no ... ? Here it's command line only.  The behaviour is weird indeed, and I don't like it, but there is a technical explanation for it (in the 'duplicate' answer I linked)

Comment: @Szabolcs yep, though many things that should be are not and I got used to trying ridiculous things.

Comment: thanks @Szabolcs, indeed that 'duplicate' answer explains in a very weird way the behavior. I hope I am safe by changing all my `-file` to `-script` calls. @Kuba, yes I also tried `NotebookFileName[]` and indeed I get the error `FrontEndObject::notavail`.

Comment: You may be able to get the information from `$ScriptCommandLine` instead.